# Checking whether a pair of values lies between a range from an array of ranges

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, dynamic-programming

> Lets say the pair of values is: 5 and 10
>
> And
>
> The array of ranges R is:
>   R = {(6,10), (5,7), (6,9), (4,12)}

In this case, it should return `True` because 5 and 10 BOTH lie between 4 and 12.

There is obviously a very easy solution in `O(N)` for this by iterating over each pair, which can further be improved by sorting the range R based on the first value of pair of values in R (though I guess sorting would make worst case O(n log n)). However, the problem is when I need to find the answer for multiple pair of values. I am looking for a better solution, probably using a `map` in some way, that reduces the need for recomputing some values. Basically, is there an approach using dynamic programming?

Any ideas? Code would be appreciated too though :P

Comment: You might be interested in segment trees.

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please give a more specific example. Do you want both elements of the pair to be in one specific range? Does the pair represents a range? For ranges (1,4),(7,9) what will be the result for pair (3,8) and why?

Comment: I think it is clear enough? This should return false because there is no range in which both 3 and 8 lie. @A.

Comment: Well, in this case if the array of ranges is already given and this is a one time task then just do the brute force of iterating over the array and checking each range. If you want some data structure then you might want to use segment tree (some kind of BST).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use maps, one solution would be to create a map of maps, one for minimums and one for maximums. This will take some preprocessing time, but overall it would be faster as the cost is amortized over a long run with many lookups.

You're basically creating a map which has keys for every valid minimum, and inside each value a map with keys for every valid maximum for that mimumum..

For example (beware, untested back-of-envelope code!):

```
// Psuedo-ish C++11

typedef std::map<int, std::vector<R>> MaxMap;
typedef std::map<int, MaxMap> MinMap;

MinMap minMap;

// Build maps
for(range : R)
{
    for(int i=range.min; i<=range.max; ++i)
    {
        MaxMap& maxMap = minMap[i];
        for(int j=range.min; j<=range.max; ++j)
        {
            // We just need some value in the map,
            // so might as well store a list of the original ranges..
            mapMap[j].push_back(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Then for lookups you take your min value and look it up in the MinMap, and then look up your maximum in the MaxMap. Remember, the MinMap gives you all the valid maximums for any given minimum, and then your lookup in the MaxMap tells you if your maximum is a valid maximum for the given minimum...

```
bool isValidRange(int min, int max)
{
    MinMap::iterator minIt = minMap.find(min);
    if(minIt == minMap.end())
    {
        return false;
    }
    MaxMap& maxMap = minIt->second;
    MaxMap::iterator maxIt = maxMap.find(max);
    if(maxIt == maxMap.end())
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of course, this only works for the natural numbers. You'll need something else if you need negatives or reals in your ranges...